# Import Excel to Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to import an excel file to Sharepoint list without using manual import (Import to Excel). Instead, I want to import automatically by specifying the path of the Excel sheet or by using any Scheduler. Suggest me...

Comment: Do you mean automatically like all Excel files in Path X should be imported as lists. So when users uploads excel files to that location it should automatically be imported as lists?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what do you mean by "manual import" but SharePoint provides you OOB functionality for this, go to view all Site Contents, there you will find the option "Import Spreadsheet", it imports automatically by specifying the path of the Excel, but if you must perform some custom action while importing the data you should consider developing a webpart